# Hide parent if all children are not visible jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coffeescript, haml

I am trying to use coffeescript to hide the title of the group with if all the li's under it are hidden, but this doesn't work. The log tells me that even when each li has `display:none` it is still visible. (i.e. this is selecting all lis, when it should only be selecting those that are visible)

```
filterGroups = () ->
  $('.group').each (idx, item) ->
    list = $(item).find("ul.bordered-list li:visible")
    console.log list.length
    if list.length == 0
      $(item).hide()
    else
      $(item).show()
```

The HAML structure looks like this:

```
ul.bordered-list
  li.group
    h3.group-name-header
    ul.bordered-list
      li
    ...
  ...
```

Comment: I just fiddled this and works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/invernizzie/LnGuT/ What's your target browser/runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments for [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) are `.each(idx, Element)`, not `.each(Element, idx)`;

```
filterGroups = () ->
  $('.group').each (idx, item) -> //correct argument order
    list = $(item).find("ul.bordered-list li:visible")
    console.log list.length
    if list.length == 0
      $(item).hide()
    else
      $(item).show()
```

You can also use the `this` keyword:

```
$('.group').each () ->
        list = $(this).find("ul.bordered-list li:visible")
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have it correct in the code and I edited my question.

Comment: My problem is that even though the li elements ARE hidden, they are being selected and added to the list